# DFLOP LTspice inputs and outputs

Tags: ltspice, flipflop, spice

I want to use the symbolic form of following DFLOP in the schematic. but I don't know which pin refers to which indicator(n001, n002, ...). for a better understanding of my question, I attached an **incorrect** schematic.

according to the help document of LTspice, I know that n001 to n005 are inputs, n006 and n007 are outputs and n008 is common. but I don't have any idea about them one by one.

```
A1 n001 n002 n003 n004 n005 n006 n007 n008 DFLOP
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope Analog Devices Corp. pays me for this...

```
A1 D 0 CLK PRE CLR Q_ Q 0 DFLOP
```

[image]

Comment: I was just going to suggest to do that, but it looks like you managed yourself. Congratulations. But, given your answer (and the other questions), it really looks like this is not a piece of software that suits you. Have you considered MicroCap, or Qucs, or Ngspice (or similar)?

Comment: @a concerned citizen, thanks man, you were always kind to me with your guidances. By the way, the problem is not with the software. The point is that I'm novice in this way.